# Eclipse StatET for R can't find installed libaries (windows)

Tags: r, eclipse, statet

I have a working Eclipse workspace for R development using the StatET plugin.  I can install libraries the normal way, for example:

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

But when I attempt to use the library:

```
library(rgdal)
```

R says:

```
Error in library(rgdal) : there is no package called 'rgdal'
```

Using the R GUI on the same computer works fine.

Also, in case it is relevent - using installed.packages() doesn't show the newly installed rgdal package when I use Eclipse.  But in the R GUI it does.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you install the package?

Comment: No, that's the strange thing, it works fine, and I've checked the download directories and the packages appear where they should!  Could it be a setup issue in Eclipse?

Comment: what does .libPaths() show you when called from Eclipse/StatET; maybe also compare that to .libPaths() from within R GUI

Comment: They are exactly the same! :o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, having Eclipse and the R GUI open at the same time was causing conflict, closing down the R GUI solved the issue